# What's the best way to view/analyse/filter huge traces/logfiles?

Tags: testing, analysis

this seems to be a reoccurring issue:
we receive a bug report for our software and with it tons of traces or logfiles.
since finding errors is much easier when having a **visualization of the log messages/events** over time it is convenient to use a tool that can display the progression of events in a graph etc.
(e.g. wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org) for analyzing network traffic)

what tool do you use for such a purpose?

the problem with most tools i used so far is that they mercilessly break down when you feed them huge data traces (> 1GB)
so some criteria for such a tool would be:

- can deal with huge input files (> 1 GB)
- is really fast (so you don't have to get coffee while a file is loading)
- has some sort of filtering mechanism

Answer (score 2):

Good thread for this. Tim Bray (formerly at Sun now at Google) had a contest a few years back on writing scripts to munge gigs of log files:
http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2007/09/20/Wide-Finder

IMHO mpi4py would now be the optimum solution in terms of implementation time, run time, scalability.

Also, think about going oldskool with AWK. In a recent contest it beat out C/C++/Java,
http://anyall.org/blog/2009/09/dont-mawk-awk-the-fastest-and-most-elegant-big-data-munging-language/

Comment: thanks! those are really interesting links that i will have to check out! currently i use some small haskell programs to filter and munge the data. while this is doable it so far does not really help me with the visualization part.

Comment: It depends. What kind of visualizations are you looking for? This site might give you some ideas. http://computationallegalstudies.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since every log files have their own format, I afraid there is no off-the-shelf components that fulfill your needs; you have to write your own visualizer.

Comment: that would i did so far but it would be nice to get some kind of framework support for that. after all, some of the problems you can have with this are not restricted to one format.

Comment: agree, but a lot of the logs from different programs can be viewed by "standard visualization software packages". Some of them even support custom patterns. 

I would prefere to make a "Company.Logging" API if I was to make that much logdata. And inside it, both have functions for WRITING and READING the logs. But thats probarbly just me :o)